# Anyway to Bypass Change Claims Step in B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We are trying to get a custom profile to use a verification code user journey and are hitting a wall with a step that seems to be built in to the `VerificationControl` `DisplayControl`s.

```
  <DisplayControl Id="verificationControl-readOnly" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyField" />
    </InputClaims>
    <DisplayClaims>
      <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="readOnlyField" Required="true" />
      <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
    </DisplayClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
       <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationStatus" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <Actions>
      <Action Id="SendCode">
        <ValidationClaimsExchange>
          <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendVerificationCode" />
        </ValidationClaimsExchange>
      </Action>
      <Action Id="VerifyCode">
        <ValidationClaimsExchange>
          <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyVerificationCode" />
        </ValidationClaimsExchange>
      </Action>
    </Actions>
  </DisplayControl>
```

It seems after we successfully verify the code, we always get prompted to change the `readOnlyField` with a `Change` and `Continue` button showing.

After looking at the html, I found that the `Change` button has the css class `changeClaims` and after searching for that with B2C, I found [this document](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy.md) which basically says, hide the button.

I've tested hiding the button in the browser with a custom `selfAsserted.cshtml` which works fine but we're still having to hit `Continue` which feels clunky.

Is there a way to skip having to hit `Continue` *after* verifying at all?